# How to prove if this $\sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{l}=2^{n}$ is valid for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: induction

Prove for for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$: $\sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{l}=2^{n}$

I know the steps of induction but i have no idea how to prove this equation with binomial coefficient.

1) For the induction base i need to take one number and it should be $n=1$. So, do i use this value $n$ for both $n$ and $l$ in the equation? In that case i believe that equation is not valid.

2) Should i for inductive claim increase both $n+1$ and $l+1$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the binomial theorem?

Comment: Technically, for the induction you may want to use $n=0$ as base case.

Comment: Also, see this page 5/6 of this document for three proofs: [Link](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM4.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the meat of your question seems to be about how to prove this claim **with induction** (*even though the other answers provide much shorter and easier proofs*), that is how I will choose to approach.

---

**Checking base case:** Here, we check that the statement is true for some starting value(s) of $n$.  The statement's truth will depend only upon $n$ as $l$ is only used as a shorthand here to make the sum easier to write (*$l$ will range between all values from $0$ to $n$ and will not be a specific single number in general*)

If you consider $0\in\Bbb N$, we start with the base case of checking if $\sum\limits_{l=0}^0\binom{0}{l}=\binom{0}{0}=\frac{0!}{0!0!}=1=2^0$, so the base case is valid.

Otherwise, for $n=1$ we check that $\sum\limits_{l=0}^1\binom{1}{l}=\binom{1}{0}+\binom{1}{1}=1+1=2=2^1$, so the base case is again valid.

---

**Inductive step:**  Again, $l$ will be all possible values in the range, so we do not change how $l$ appears in the inductive step.  We assume that the statement $2^n = \sum\limits_{l=0}^n \binom{n}{l}$ is true for some $n$ and we wish to prove that from this it follows that it is true for the next value, $n+1$.

Here, we rely on something known as pascal's identity: $\binom{n+1}{r} = \binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}$.

Examining the case of $n+1$, we have then:

$$\begin{array}{rlr}\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{l}&=\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n}{l}+\binom{n}{l-1}\right)&\text{via pascal's identity}\\
&=\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{l}\right)+\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{l-1}\right)&\text{by splitting into separate summations}\\
&=\left(\binom{n}{n+1}+\sum\limits_{l=0}^n\binom{n}{l}\right) + \left(\binom{n}{-1}+\sum\limits_{l=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{l-1}\right)&\text{by breaking off last and first pieces respectively}\\
&=\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{l}\right)+\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{l}\right)&\text{broken off terms equalled zero and reindexing of right}\\
&=2^n+2^n&\text{by induction hypothesis}\\
&=2\cdot (2^n)=2^{n+1}&\text{by simplification}\end{array}$$

Hence, it follows that it is true for $n+1$ as well, therefore by induction the statement is true for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: And can you give me any hint how could I prove it easier, without induction?

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a set with $n$ elements, then $\binom{n}{l}$ is the number of subsets of $S$ with $l$ elements.

$\sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{l}$ is then the number of all subsets of $S$ and this is equal to $2^{n}$ because the subsets of $S$ can be put into bijection with the set of $n$-bit strings.

Answer (score 1):

For a prove by induction:

You can start the induction at $n=0$, which is trivial. So let $n$ be greater than $0$

> This is actually needed in the calculations that follow, since we will use the induction hypothesis on $n-1$ which should not be smaller than $0$

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 
&= 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} + 1 \\
&= 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left[ \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k} \right] + 1 \\
&= 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}  + 1 \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} \\
&= 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}  = 2\cdot 2^{n-1} 
\end{align}
In the last step the induction hypothesis was used.

Answer (score 0):

The **binomial coefficient** $n\choose i$ is *by definition*, the **coefficient** of $x^i$ in the expanded **binomial** $(1+x)^n$, i.e., $(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}x^i$. Use this definition with $x=1$.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen $\binom{n}{i}$ defined that way. The definition $\binom{n}{i} = |\{ A \subseteq \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \} : |A|=i \}|$ is far more common, in which case there is more work to be done. The definition $\binom{n}{i} = \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$ is (abhorrent but) also common (when $i \le n$).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah if you use binomial theorem ..then $$\sum_{l=0}^{n} nC_l=^nC_0+^nC_1+^nC_2+...... $$
Which is equal to $$1+ ^nC_1+^nC_2+....+^nC_n $$
That is $(1+1)^n$ ...taking x=1and a=1 in the expansion of $(x+a)^n$